# unsigned 64bit integer vs. 64-bit unsigned integer?

Tags: programming

I found several way to write the same thing, but it may be that only one is really correct, can you help me to find the correct sentence. I want to specify the type of a parameter for a function (a C programming API).

What is the correct version ? 1,2,3 or 4 ? And for `bit`should I use `s` as their are 64 ? :)

- unsigned 64bit integer (1)
- unsigned 64-bit integer (2)
- 64-bit unsigned integer (3)
- 64bit unsigned integer (4)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All are correct, if only because the way that the adjectives work in this context is quite unusual.

The general adjective order in English is; Quantity or number, Quality or opinion, Size, Age, Shape, Color, Proper adjective (nationality, place of origin, material), Purpose or qualifier.

Now, "64-bit" could be considered quantity or size, but could also be considered purpose or qualifier, as could unsigned. As such, both positioning the size before or after the sign is justifiable.

Between "64-bit" and "64bit", the former is using a number, unit and hyphen to form an adjective, while the latter is combining a number and unit to give a measurement, which in turn is an adjective. Again, both are allowed.

Now, because we *could* consider the number to be a size, people will more often favour either 3 or 4 rather than 1 or 2. It's also more common to use the hyphen here, so 2 or 3 rather than 1 or 4. So while all four are allowed, "64-bit unsigned integer" would be the more common.

Plural forms would be incorrect, you don't use the plural when using a unit in a description, so "a 64-bit unsigned integer is an unsigned integer with 64 bits".

Answer (score 0):

I think that the use of plural is not necessary in this case: 64-bit means "made up of 64 bits", which is precisely what you want. And I think that "unsigned" should go first, as the adjectives are usually ordered by "generality", with the "most general" going first.

I think (2) or "unsigned 64-bit integer" is correct.